# perl list path of subdirectory using File::Find

Tags: perl, file-find

How can I get all the paths of a subdirectory `foo` into an array in perl using `File::Find`

```
 abc\def\sdfg\gthrth\foo\
 abc\def\fgfdg\foo\
 abc\def\sdfgdsg\fgdfg\gfdgf\tytty\foo\
 abc\def\foo\
```

I want to get the full paths of all subdirectories `foo` inside directory `abc\def` into an array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
use File::Find::Rule qw( );

my @paths = File::Find::Rule->name('foo')->in(@dirs);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Find;

my @foo_paths;

sub is_it_foo {
   if ( m,^foo$, ) { 
       push ( @foo_paths, $File::Find::name ); 
   }
}

find ( \&is_it_foo, "abc/def" );
```